# GLTFLoader gives cannot Import outside of module

Tags: html, three.js

With the updates to THREE.js, I have been having trouble using the GLTFLoader. It keeps giving me the error mentioned above.

Imported in a seperate js file

test.js

```
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";
```

index.html

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
```

file structure

Answer (score 1):

The import statement cannot be used in embedded scripts unless the script has a type="module".

Here is an example for the import statement with type module.

```
<script type="module" src="test.js"></script>
```